# insert a random number into each row in table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I currently have an oracle table (lovalarm) containing around 600,000 rows.  I need to be able to run a query which will cycle through each row and update a field (lovsiteid) to a random number between 14300 and 17300.

So far I have:

```
update lovalarm
set lovsiteid = (select TRUNC(dbms_random.value(14300,17300)) FROM dual)
```

Sadly this picks a random number and then updates all rows with the same number which isn't exactly what I'm after!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,
Cap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just not use subquery:

```
update lovalarm
set lovsiteid = TRUNC(dbms_random.value(14300,17300))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
update lovalarm set lovsiteid = (select FLOOR(RAND() * (17300 - 14300) + 14300))
```

works in MySQL